# Approximate Brun's Constant

Tags: code-golf, math, number-theory, primes, approximation

[Brun's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brun%27s_theorem) is the value to which the sum of the reciprocals of [twin prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime) pairs (`1/p` and `1/(p+2)` where `p` and `p+2` are both prime) converges. It is approximately `1.902160583104`.

Given a positive integer `N`, approximate Brun's constant by summing the reciprocals of the twin prime pairs where both primes in the pair are less than `N`, and output the approximation.

### Rules

- `N` will be a positive integer within the representable range for your language.
- The output must be as accurate as possible to the true value, within the limits of your language's floating-point implementation, ignoring any potential issues due to floating-point arithmetic inaccuracies. If your language is capable of arbitrary-precision arithmetic, it must be at least as precise as IEEE 754 double-precision arithmetic.
- Alternatively, an exact fraction may be output in any consistent, unambiguous format.
- If a prime appears in multiple twin prime pairs (e.g. `5`, part of both `(3, 5)` and `(5, 7)`), its reciprocal contributes to the sum each time.

### Test Cases

```
2 -> 0
6 -> 0.5333333333333333
10 -> 0.8761904761904762
13 -> 0.8761904761904762
100 -> 1.3309903657190867
620 -> 1.4999706034568274
100000 -> 1.67279958482774
```

Comment: Can an exact fraction be output?

Comment: @LegionMammal978 Yes, I'll clarify.

Comment: Side note: the value 1.902160583104... for Brun's constant is only conjectured; not even the first significant figure has been rigorously computed (that is, it's not even known whether it's greater than or less than 2).

Comment: @GregMartin While that's true, it's also the best approximation we currently have.

Comment: 5 is the only prime that appears in two prime pairs

Comment: @ChristianSievers My number theory is a bit rusty in places, so I opted for safe rather than sorry. :)

Comment: He's right though. All primes larger than 3 must be coprime with 6, so they're congruent to 1 or -1 modulo 6. If p, p+2, and p+4 are all prime, one of them is congruent to 3 modulo 6, which is only possible if one of them (p, to be precise) is *equal* to 3.

Answer (score 26):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>78</s> <s>77</s> <s>75</s> <s>70</s> <s>68</s> 62 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,k=3,m=1,j=0:k<n and-m%k*j*2/k+f(n,k+2,m*k**4,m%k/k)
```

*Thanks to @xnor for golfing off <s>2</s> 4 bytes and paving the way for 4 more!*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#FYxBCsIwFETXeorZhDbpr00TyaIY7xIpgTbmK0XPH7@LYQbe8FqOz1QfawJTiZ5qnGmPdik3RuJ1rKqY3bipDLmXx@CommLMlQRMRbf8OsDYGI4QCLOV@H/LCM4u59P72PjTd8p/Md6hLnPIHRTEBlFqrdsP)

#### Background

Recall that [Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem) states that for all integers **k > 1**,

[image]

where **a ≡ b (mod d)** means that **a - b** is evenly divisible by **d**, i.e., **a** and **b** have the same residue when divided by **d**.

In [Wilson Theorems for Double-, Hyper-, Sub- and Super-factorials](https://arxiv.org/abs/1302.3676), the authors prove generalizations for double factorials, on which this answer builds. The [double factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial) of an integer **k ≥ 0** is defined by

[image]

Theorem 4 of the aforementioned paper states the following.

[image]

Elevating both sides of the congruences to the fourth power, we deduce that

[image]

for all odd primes **p**. Since **1!! = 1**, the equivalence holds also for **p = 2**.

Now, doing the same to Wilson's theorem reveals that

[image]

Since

[image]

it follows that

[image]

whenever **p** is prime.

Now, let **k** be an odd, positive, composite integer. By definition, there exist integers **a, b > 1** such that **k = ab**.

Since **k** is odd, so are **a** and **b**. Thus, both occur in the sequence **1, 3, …, k - 2** and

[image]

where **|** indicates divisibility.

Summing up, for all odd integers **k > 1**

[image]

where **p(k) = 1** if **k** is prime and **p(k) = 0** if **k** is composite.

#### How it works

When the function **f** is called with a single argument, **k**, **m**, and **j** are initialized as **3**, **1**, and **0**.

Note that **((k - 2)!!)<sup>4</sup> = 1!!<sup>4</sup> = 1 = m**. In fact, the equality **m = ((k - 2)!!)<sup>4</sup>** will hold at all times. **j** is a *float* and will always be equal to **((k - 4)!!)<sup>4</sup> % (k - 2) / (k - 2)**.

While \$k < n\$, the right argument of `and` will get evaluated. Since \$j = \frac{\mod(\left(\left(k - 4\right)!!\right)^4 , k - 2)}{k - 2}\$, as proven in the first paragraph, \$j = \frac{1}{k - 2}\$ if \$k - 2\$ is prime and \$j = 0\$ if not. Likewise, since \$\mod(m,k) = \left(\left(k - 2\right)!!\right)^4\$ equals \$1\$ if \$k\$ is prime and \$0\$ if not, \$\mod(-m,k) = k - 1\$ if \$k\$ is prime and \$\mod(-m , k) = 0\$ if not. Therefore, `-m%k*j*2/k` evaluates to \$\frac{2\left(k - 1\right)}{k\left(k - 2\right)} = \frac{\left(k - 2\right) + k}{k(k - 2)} = \frac{1}{k} + \frac{1}{k - 2}\$ if the pair \$\left(k - 2, k\right)\$ consists of twin primes and to \$0\$ if not.

After computing the above, we add the result to the return value of the recursive call `f(n,k+2,m*k**4,m%k/k)`. \$k\$ gets incremented by \$2\$ so it only takes odd values<sup>‡†</sup>, we multiply \$m\$ by \$k^4\$ since \$mk^4 = \left(\left(k - 2\right)!!\right)^4k^4 = \left(k!!\right)^4\$, and pass the current value of \$\frac{\mod(m,k)}{k}\$ – which equals \$\frac{1}{k}\$ if the "old" \$k\$ is a prime and \$0\$ if not – as parameter \$j\$ to the function call.

Finally, once \$k\$ is equal to or greater than \$n\$, \$f\$ will return *False* and the recursion stops. The return value of \$f(n)\$ will be the sum of all \$\frac{1}{k} + \frac{1}{k - 2}\$ such \$\left(k - 2, k\right)\$ is a twin prime pair and \$k < n\$, as desired.

---

<sup>‡</sup> <sub>The results from the *Background* paragraph hold only for odd integers. Since even integers cannot be twin primes, we can skip them safely.</sub>

Comment: I think your expression is the same as `m%k*(j/k+j/(k-2))`.

Comment: Yes, that works. Thanks!

Comment: [Another save](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#FYzLCsIwFETX@hWzCW3SW5uHZFGM/xIpgfaaVIpu/fUYF8MMnOHUFJ4xP5aIQhwc5WBoC3rmW0EsC7JgtSmrviNPPKS@vQZLWbFSV2pwYlnTfqBgLbAETzC6xf27DW/1fD69jrW8@064D8Y7xMX41EGg2dCUUsr6Aw)

Comment: Nice observation that `((k-2)!!)^4 = p(k)` modulo `p` for odd `p`. I haven't worked through your argument, but here's one I came up with (that might be the same in essence). Work modulo `p` in the set `{1,2,..,p-1}`, the evens are exactly the negatives of the odds. So, `prod(odds) = ± prod(evens)`. Wilson's Theorem tells us that `prod(all) = - p(k)`. Since `prod(all) = prod(odds) * prod(evens) = prod(odds) * ± prod(evens)`, we have  `prod(odds)^2 = ±p(k)` and so `prod(odds)^4 = p(k)^2 = p(k)`.

Comment: Nice! I tried expressing the sum as a single fraction, but computing part of it in **j** hadn't occurred to me. Thanks again! Your proof is a lot simpler than the one from the paper.

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>15</s> 14 bytes

```
’ÆRµ_2fµ+2;µİS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/@oYebhtqBDW@ON0g5t1TayPrT1yIbg/0f3HG5/1LTG/f9/Ix0FMx0FQwMgNgbRQIaZkQEA)

#### How it works

```
’ÆRµ_2fµ+2;µİS  Main link. Argument: n

’               Decrement; yield n-1.
 ÆR             Prime range; yield all primes in [1, ..., n-1].
   µ            New chain. Argument: r (prime range)
    _2          Subtract 2 from all primes.
      f         Filter; keep all p-2 that appear in r.
       µ        New chain. Argument: t (filtered range)
        +2      Add 2 to all primes in s.
          ;     Concatenate with s.
           µ    New chain. Argument: t (twin primes)
            İ   Take the inverses.
             S  Sum.
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>16</s> 14 bytes (with a little help from @Dennis)

```
’ÆRṡ2_/2+$$ÐḟFİS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/@oYebhtqCHOxcaeR7pPrT08IQ0I7cjG4L/RxvpmOkYGugYGgNJAx0zI4PYw@2Pmtb8BwA)

While trying to improve my previous answer, I thought up a totally different algorithm, and it comes in somewhat shorter. I'm using a different post for it, as is the standard here for an answer that uses a different technique.

Dennis suggesting replacing `_/2+$$Ðḟ` with `Iċ¥Ðf2`; I'd completely forgotten about the possibility of a dyadic filter. As such, this algorithm now ties with the one that Dennis' answer used.

### Explanation

```
’ÆRṡ2Iċ¥Ðf2FİS
’                  Decrement.
 ÆR                Primes from 2 to the argument inclusive
                   (i.e. 2 to the original input exclusive).
   ṡ2              Take overlapping slices of size 2.
        Ðf         Keep only elements where the following is true:
       ¥           {the second parse of, which parses like this}
     Iċ   2          the differences (I) contain (ċ) 2
           F       Flatten.
            İ      Take 1/x {for every list element}.
             S     Sum.
```

Comment: `2_/2+$$Ðḟ` can become `Iċ¥Ðf2`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 17 [bytes](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog/wiki/Code-page)

```
{>I-₂:I{ṗ/₁}ᵐ}ᶠc+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#ASMA3P//ez5JLeKCgjpJe@G5ly/igoF94bWQfeG2oGMr//82MjD/Wg)

This is the brand new version of Brachylog, with a shiny code page!

#### Explanation

```
{            }ᶠ        Find all valid outputs of the predicate in brackets
               c+      Output is the sum of that list after flattening it

 >I                    Input > I
   -₂:I                The list [I-2, I]
       {   }ᵐ          Map:
        ṗ/₁              Must be prime and the output is its inverse
```

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 16 bytes

```
liqZqtd2=)t2+h/s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@5@TGVVYkmJkq1lipJ2hX/z/v5mRAQA)

Consider input `13` as an example.

```
l     % Push 1
      %   STACK: 1
i     % Input N
      %   STACK: 1, 13
q     % Subtract 1
      %   STACK: 1, 12
Zq    % Primes up to that
      %   STACK: 1, [2 3 5 7 11]
t     % Duplicate
      %   STACK: 1, [2 3 5 7 11], [2 3 5 7 11]
d     % Consecutive differences
      %   STACK: 1, [2 3 5 7 11], [1 2 2 4]
2=    % Compare with 2, element-wise
      %   STACK: 1, [2 3 5 7 11], [0 1 1 0]
)     % Use as logical index to select elements from array
      %   STACK: 1, [3 5]
t     % Duplicate
      %   STACK: 1, [3 5], [3 5]
2+    % Add 2, element-wise
      %   STACK: 1, [3 5], [5 7]
h     % Concatenate horizontally
      %   STACK: 1, [3 5 5 7]
/     % Divide, element-wise
      %   STACK: [0.3333 0.2 0.2 0.1429]
s     % Sum of array. Implicitly display
      %   STACK: 0.8762
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>19</s> 14 bytes (-5 @Emigna)

```
<LDpÏÍDpÏDÌ«zO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@2/j41JwuN/l0FKjwOJDK4qBTCPtQ6ur/P//NzQGAA)

Comment: `<LDpÏÍDpÏDÌ«zO` to save 5 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, <s>48</s> 47 bytes

*Thanks to JungHwan Min for saving 1 byte!*

```
If[PrimeQ/@(i&&(g=i-2)),1/i+1/g,0]~Sum~{i,#-1}&
```

Unnamed function taking a positive integer as input and returning an exact fraction; for example, `If[PrimeQ/@(i&&(g=i-2)),1/i+1/g,0]~Sum~{i,#-1}&[10]` returns `92/105`.

`If[PrimeQ/@(i&&(g=i-2)),1/i+1/g,0]` tests whether both `i` and `i-2` are prime, returning the sum of their reciprocals if so and `0` if not. `~Sum~{i,#-1}&` then returns the sum of those contributions for all values of `i` less than the input.

Previous submission:

```
If[And@@PrimeQ@{i,g=i-2},1/i+1/g,0]~Sum~{i,#-1}&
```

Comment: Now that's just spooky. I give up. ⚐

Comment: I wondered if "exact fraction" meant Mathematica :)

Comment: -1 byte: `If[PrimeQ/@(i&&(g=i-2)),1/i+1/g,0]~Sum~{i,#-1}&`

Comment: One can get an arbitrary-precision number by adding two bytes, `N@`, in front of the code.

Comment: Nice golfing of the condition! It's true that `N` returns a decimal approximation to a real number; however, it requires extra bytes to display more than 6 sig figs or so, and no matter how many sig figs are displayed, it's still less accurate than the fraction itself.

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>67</s> 66 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @Arnauld*

```
f=n=>--n>1&&((p=x=>n%--x?p(x):x==1)(n)&&p(n-=2)&&1/n+++1/++n)+f(n)
```

Outputs `false` for test case `2`, which is [allowed by default](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9067/12012).

#### Test snippet

```js
f=n=>--n>1&&((p=x=>n%--x?p(x):x==1)(n)&&p(n-=2)&&1/n+++1/++n)+f(n)

g=n=>console.log("Input:",n,"Output:",f(n))

g(2)
g(6)
g(10)
g(13)
g(100)
g(620)
```

Comment: I think `1/n+++1/++n` saves a byte.

Comment: @Arnauld Thanks. For some reason I didn't know that `+++` doesn't *always* throw an error...

Answer (score 2):

## Octave, 45 bytes

```
@(n)sum(all(isprime(m=[h=3:n-1;h-2]))*m'.^-1)
```

Explanation:

```
m=[h=3:n-1;h-2]             generate an concatenate two ranges 3:n-1 and 1:n-3
rec=m'.^-1                  transpose and reciprocal
idx=all(isprime(m))         create a logical [0 1 ..] array  if both ranges are prime set 1 else set 0
sum1 = idx * rec            matrix multiplication(extrat elements with logical index and sum along the first dimension)
sum(sum1)                   sum along the second dimension
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/#blfF2)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 19 bytes

```
’ÆRḊµ_Æp=2Tịµ_2;µİS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/@oYebhtqCHO7oObY0/3FZgaxTycHc3kG1kfWjrkQ3B/6ONdMx0DA10DI2BpIGOmZFB7OH2R01r/gMA)

I have a feeling that this is improvable, but I can't immediately see how.

### Explanation

```
’ÆRḊµ_Æp=2Tịµ_2;µİS
 ÆR                  Generate all primes from 2 to n inclusive
’                    Subtract 1
   Ḋ                 Remove first element
’ÆRḊ                 Generate all primes from 3 to n-1 exclusive

     _Æp             Subtract the previous prime (i.e. calculate the prime gap)
        =2           Compare to 2
          Tị         Take elements of the input where the comparison is true
     _Æp=2Tị         Filter a list of primes to the latter halves of prime pairs

             _2      Subtract 2
               ;     Append
             _2;     Append the list to the list with 2 subtracted from it
                 İ   Take reciprocals
                  S  Sum
                 İS  Take the sum of the reciprocals
```

The `µ` connect all these portions together pipeline-style, with each taking the output of the one before as its input.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth - <s>22</s> <s>21</s> 17 bytes

I think that refactoring will help.

```
scL1sf.APM_MTm,tt
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=scL1sf.APM_MTm%2Ctt&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=2%0A6%0A10%0A13%0A100%0A620&debug=0).

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 0.4](http://julialang.org/), <s>48</s> 46 bytes

```julia
!n=sum(1./[(p=n-1|>primes)∩(p-2);p∩(p+2)])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/julia#@6@YZ1tcmqthqKcfrVFgm6drWGNXUJSZm1qs@ahjpUaBrpGmdQGYpW2kGav5Py2/SCFPITNPQcNIx0zH0EDH0BhIGuiYGRlocnE6ALXmlaRpKKkalyro2imo6hmapcXkKenk6SjmaXKl5qX8BwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), <s>59</s> 51 bytes

<s>`{sum 1 «/»grep((*-(2&0)).is-prime,^$_).flatmap:{$_-2,$_}}`</s>

```
{sum 1 «/»grep(*.all.is-prime,(-2..*Z ^$_)).flat}
```

`-2..* Z ^$_` zips the infinite list `-2, -1, 0, 1, ...` with the list `0, 1, ... $_-1` (`$_` being the argument to the function), producing the list `(-2, 0), (-1, 1), (0, 2), ..., ($_-3, $_-1)`.  (Obviously none of these numbers less than 3 can be in a prime pair, but `3..* Z 5..^$_` is a few bytes longer, and none of the extra numbers are prime.)

The `grep` selects only those pairs where all (that is, both) numbers are prime, and the `flat` flattens them into a plain list of numbers.

`«/»` is the division hyperoperator; with the list on the right and `1` on the left, it turns the list of prime pairs into their reciprocals, which is then summed by `sum`.

Answer (score 1):

## Clojure, 147 bytes

```clojure
(fn[n](let[p #(if(> % 2)(<(.indexOf(for[a(range 2 %)](mod % a))0)0))](reduce +(for[a(range 2 n)](if(and(p a)(p(- a 2)))(+(/ 1 a)(/ 1(- a 2)))0)))))
```

And Clojure comes dead last, as usual.

Ungolfed:

```clojure
; Returns the primality of a number.
(defn prime? [n]
  (if (> n 2)
    (< (.indexOf (for [a (range 2 n)] (mod n a)) 0) 0)))

; Calculates the actual Brun's Constant. ' (Stupid highlighter)
(defn brunsconst [n]
  ; Adds all of the entries together
  (reduce
    +
    ; For a in range(2, n):
    (for [a (range 2 n)]
      (let [b (- a 2)]
        ; If both a and a-2 are prime:
        (if (and (prime? a) (prime? b))
          ; Place (1/a + 1/a-2) on the array, else 0
          (+ (/ 1 a) (/ 1 b)) 0)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

## APL NARS, 216 bytes, 108 chars

```
  r←z n;h;i;k;v
  i←0⋄n-←1⋄h←1+⍳n-1⋄→B
A:k←i⊃h⋄h←k∪(0≠k∣h)/h
B:→A×⍳(⍴h)≥i+←1
  r←+/÷(v-2),v←(h=1⌽h+2)/h
```

this would use the "Crivello di Eratostene" for find the sublist in 1..arg of request primes. Test:

```
  z¨2 6 10 13 100 620
0 0.5333333333 0.8761904762 0.8761904762 1.330990366 1.499970603 
  z 100000
1.672799585
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 14 bytes

```
ṁ\Σfo=2F-Ẋefṗŀ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f9odXNr///huYFczqNmbz0yRi3huoplZuG5l8WA////MTAw)

#### Explanation

```
ṁ\Σfo=2F-Ẋefṗŀ
             ŀ   lowered range, 0..n-1
           fṗ    filter primes
         Ẋe      get each consecutive pair
   f   F-        filter where difference
    o=2          equals 2
  Σ              concat, list of pairs to flattened list
ṁ\               map 1/n and then sum
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 50 bytes

```
n->forprime(p=s=0.,n,isprime(q=p-2)&&s+=1/p+1/q);s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYrBCsMwDEN/xfRQYpq0SQa9FPdHxg49LCOweW6yy74@czuB0JOQbCW7h7QE1Nit6V2k5NfdCFXyo2Wb63/YSVzEvq8DhUmGMO241LaJPL@Gwa2gN/4odkfpIBlGtHCNFmYLwasvRyrM0Z@kumH7AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `sḋ`, <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```
~æ2l'÷ε2=;fĖ
```

[Try it online](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJz4biLIiwiIiwifsOmMmwnw7fOtTI9O2bEliIsIiIsIjEwMCJd) or [verify all test cases](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJz4biLQSIsIiIsIn7DpjJsJ8O3zrUyPTtmxJYiLCIiLCIyXG42XG4xMFxuMTNcbjEwMFxuNjIwIl0=).

Explanation:

```
~             # Filter the range 0 to n-1 by:
 æ            #   Is prime
  2l          # Get the overlapping groups of 2
    '    ;    # Filter those by:
     ÷ε       #   Absolute difference of the list
       2=     #   Equals 2
          f   # Flatten to make one list
           Ė  # Take the reciprocal of each
              # Sum with the s flag
              # Convert to decimal format with the ḋ flag
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + GNU utilities, <s>86</s> 85 bytes

```bash
for((k=4;k<$1;k++,j=k-2)){ [ `factor $k $j|wc -w` = 4 ]&&x=$x+1/$k+1/$j;};bc -l<<<0$x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@5@WX6ShkW1rYp1to2Jona2trZNlm61rpKlZrRCtkJCWmFySX6Sgkq2gklVTnqygW56gYKtgohCrplZhq1Khbaivkg0isqxrrZOA0jk2NjYGKhX///83AwA)

Constructs a large arithmetic expression and then feeds it to `bc -l` to evaluate it.

*Edit: Mistakenly left in a $(...) pair from an old version with nested command substitution; changed to backticks to save a byte.*